# How can i simplify an if/else statement to add a class in pug/jade?

Tags: node.js, pug

So I have an array of posts and I want to create a carousel with them.
I'd like to know if i can simplify this code so it doesn't look so bad, and not repeat the same code just because i need to add a class to a div element.

```
for v, i in arr
    if i === 0
        .carousel-item.active
            img(src=v.banner.toString())
                .container
                    .carousel-caption.text-left
                        h1= v.name
                        p= v.description
                        p
                            a.btn.btn-lg.btn-primary(href=v.id, role='button') More!
    else
        .carousel-item
            img(src=v.banner.toString())
                .container
                    .carousel-caption.text-left
                        h1= v.name
                            p= v.description
                            p
                                a.btn.btn-lg.btn-primary(href=v.id, role='button') More!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address this (very common) problem Pug allows you to pass either an array or an object to the `class` attribute. An object makes more sense in your case as you can easily map a class name (`active`) to a boolean indicating whether the class should be added (`i === 0`).

```
.carousel-item(class={ active: i === 0 })
```

You can learn more useful tricks like this on the [*Attributes* page of Pug's documentation](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html).